# Does the site also need a subtitle?

Tags: discussion, site-name

In parallel with deciding on a name, should we also be thinking about a subtitle? For example, CrossValidated is winning right now, but that doesn't say everything that we need to have said about the scope of this site, e.g. CrossValidated: A collaboratively edited question and answer site for statistics, machine learning, and statistical programming?  Alternatively, do we need text to fill something like what is in the "about" box for unlogged in users at StackOverflow?  There they have "StackOverflow is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers".

Answer (score 1):

There is something like this already developed by the SE team: "Q&A for statisticians, data analysts, data miners and data visualization experts"

Comment: But since we added statistical computing to our scope should that also be in there?